# Autostart installed package with Python

Tags: python, packaging, python-wheel

Given a package `random.whl` containing `hello.py`:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

Is there a way to create a `setup.py`, `setup.cfg` or `pyproject.toml`, that when executed, will install the package in such a way that `hello.py` will be executed every time Python is started?

```
pip install random.whl
python unrelated.py  # First prints "Hello World", then continues on.
```

I know it's possible to hook on `readline.py` that Python automatically loads, but is there a different and less "hacky" way to achieve it?

Some impossible ways that I thought of:

- Running a post-install script on a `.whl` distribution (post-install is only avaiable on `sdist`).
- Modifying `PYTHONSTARTUP` env variable or copying files.
- Changing the import machinery.

While being a security risk, a method achieving it is good for implementing debuggers or auditing tools without requiring a change in either pre-compiled or post-compiled Python code, or used for penetration testing in side-channel attacks.

Comment: You want to run random code when installing a wheel? Please don't.

Comment: @thebjorn For my use case it's a requirement. Less random code, more Python code at Python startup, but random code can achieve it. It isn't a secret of course that it's already possible. I wonder if there's a less-disgusting-way of doing it :-)

Comment: "While being a security risk.." is my main problem with this scheme. We don't want inherent security risks to be conveniently accessible. Have your users run a command post-installation instead (`mytool init` or some-such).

Comment: @thebjorn I deal with cybersecurity. Mitigating / POCing it in public so a fix can be thought of is exactly my intention. Since it's already possible, and Python automatically runs `sdist` with custom scripts included, I wonder if there's any cleaner way of achieving it using `whl`without resorting to more hacky methods.

Comment: To my knowledge there is not.

Comment: Seems like `sitecustomize`, `usercustomize`, and `pth` files also work.

Answer (score 0):

So far, using `sitecustomize.py` and publishing an `sdist` with a custom `install` command was the most reliable, and worked in virtual environments unlike `usercustomize.py` or `.pth` files.

Relevant `setup.py` code:

```
import sys
import os
import setuptools
import sysconfig
from setuptools.command.install import install

class PreInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        site_packages_dir = sysconfig.get_path("purelib")
        sitecustomize_path = os.path.join(site_packages_dir, "sitecustomize.py")
        if os.path.exists(sitecustomize_path):
            raise FileExistsError("Site customize file already exists. "
                                  "Please remove it before installing.")
        install.run(self)

setuptools.setup(
    name='...',
    version='0.0.1',
    py_modules=["sitecustomize"],
    cmdclass={'install': PreInstall,},
)
```

It still doesn't work with `.whl` distributions as it might overwrite an existing `sitecustomize` without being able to check.